# Need Command Line interface for electron app

Tags: linux, windows, electron, command-line-interface, electron-packager

I have built electron, node.js is serving angular /dist. The application is distributed in windows and linux. I need to configure the app such that it is accessible via cmd or bash shell.

This is how I build  my app for linux and windows,

```
"builderForLinux": "electron-packager --out linx64 --overwrite --platform linux --appname myApp .  --executable-name myApp --asar",
"builderForWindows": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform winx64 --appname myApp .  --executable-name myApp --asar"
```

Comment: what happens if you type `/full/path/to/myApp --help` ? Good luck.